# proc sql filter for values that end in a list of strings

Tags: sql, sas

I have an example table:

```
data data;
    length code $30;
    input code$;
    datalines;
PPPES
PPPEW
pppESS
saf
xwq3
er32
ddES
ea9ESS
asesEo
ewlEa
;
run;
```

and I want to filter for rows that end in ES, ESS, or EW. I tried the following but it didn't work:

```
proc sql;
create table revised as
select * 
from data
where code like ("%ES", "%ESS", "%EW") 
quit;
```

Is there a way to filter if a variable ends in a possible list of string values?

This is my desired output:

```
data data1;
    length code $30;
    input code$;
    datalines;
PPPES
PPPEW
pppESS
ddES
ea9ESS
;
run;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

Either explicitly test for each string.

```
where code like '%ES' or code like '%ESS' or code like '%EW'
```

In a data step you could use either of these:

```
if left(reverse(code)) in: ('SE','SSE','WE');
where left(reverse(code)) in: ('SE','SSE','WE');
```

PROC SQL does not support the truncated comparisons specified by the : modifier. But you could use the WHERE= dataset option

```
from data(where=(left(reverse(code)) in: ('SE','SSE','WE')))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using "or" and simple quotation marks:

```
    data data;
        length code $30;
        input code$;
        datalines;
    PPPES
    PPPEW
    pppESS
    saf
    xwq3
    er32
    ddES
    ea9ESS
    asesEo
    ewlEa
    ;
    run;
    
    proc sql;
        create table revised as
            select * 
            from data
            where code like ('%ES') or code like ('%ESS') or code like ('%EW');
    quit;
```

Answer (score 0):

In some scenarios you may want to `cross join` your search terms (as data) with your data, or do an existential test on your data.

```
data endings;
  length target $10;
  input target $char10.;
  datalines;
ES
ESS
EW
;

data have;
    length code $30;
    input code $char30.;
    datalines;
PPPES
PPPEW
pppESS
saf
xwq3
er32
ddES
ea9ESS
asesEo
ewlEa
;
run;

* cross join;
proc sql;
  create table want as 
  select distinct code 
  from have
  cross join endings
  having code like '%'||target
  ;
quit;

* existential test;
proc sql;
  create table want as
  select distinct code from have
  where exists (
    select * from endings
    where code like '%'||target
  );
quit;
```

You might also need to deal with case insensitive searches by uppercasing the data values.